# check if scanf is an int in a loop

Tags: c

I want to get a number between 1 to 10 and I wrote this :

```
 while(1){
     scanf("%d",&x);
     if( !(0<x && x<11) ){
       puts("invalid input");
       continue;
       }
     break;
         }
```

but when I enter a character it stucks on an infinite loop and just print "invalid input".what is the problem with that?

Comment: Curious, what value did you expect `x` to have when you entered a character with `scanf("%d",&x);`?

Comment: This condition:

    if( !(0<x && x<11) ){

does not test for x between 1 and 10.  Try this instead:

     if (x > 0 && x < 11) {

Comment: @bruceg Hmmm `if( !(0<x && x<11) ){
       puts("invalid input");` looks OK.  What value of `x` would not give the desired result?

Comment: @chux characters like a

Comment: thanks everyone,problem solved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003965/scanf-in-a-do-while-loop-causes-infinite-loop-even-with-test-of-input

Comment: @Ayo What type is `x`?

Comment: @chux it's int but I was worrying if the user makes a mistake.